# How avoid mouseenter event while I use sortable of jquery-ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using the mouseenter event to display information about an item in the list (the information is obtained through the generation of a route):

```
$(document).on("mouseenter","#div_example li", function(){

 $("#div_info").load(Routing.generate('show_info', {id:$(this).attr("id")}), function(){
 });

});
```

Also I'm using sortable jquery-ui to be able to drag items from one list to another:

```
$( ".sortable" ).sortable({connectWith: ".sortable",

placeholder: "ui-state-highligh",
start: function(event, ui){
 ui.item.css("cursor","none");
 ....
},
stop: function(event, ui){ 
 ui.item.css("cursor","pointer");
 ...
},
over: function(event, ui){

  ...
},
out: function(event, ui){

},
receive: function(event, ui) {

}
}).disableSelection();
```

And I need that information displayed while I use sortable, but mouseenter modifies that information when I go through another list.

I have used the following code to solve it with the help of another div where the information is displayed while using sortable, but I would like to know how to avoid it without having to do a fudge like this.

```
$( ".sortable" ).sortable({connectWith: ".sortable",

placeholder: "ui-state-highligh",
start: function(event, ui){
 ui.item.css("cursor","none");

  $("#div_info_drag").css("style","display:block;");
  $("#div_info").css("style","display:none;");

  $("#div_info_drag").load(Routing.generate('show_info',{id:ui.item.attr("id")}), function(){
  });

},
stop: function(event, ui){ 
 ui.item.css("cursor","pointer");

  $("#div_info").empty();
  $("#div_info_drag").empty();
  $("#div_info_drag").css("style","display:none;");
  $("#div_info").css("style","display:block;");
},
over: function(event, ui){

  ...
},
out: function(event, ui){

},
receive: function(event, ui) {

}
}).disableSelection();
```

How could I prevent mouseenter from running while using sortable?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("#div_info").unbind("mouseenter");
$("#div_info").unbind("mouseleave");
```